# Scala if-else condition not working on REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I am executing this on the Scala Interpreter - REPL, I am trying to set the value of the Tuple(account_df_index, disposition_df_index) to (0,1), but on execution an error is thrown on the first line of the else block. If my understanding is correct, (0,1) should be assigned and the else block must not execute. Where am I wrong?

```
val extra_params = None
val extra_params_map = if (extra_params.equals(None)) {None} else{
    extra_params.toMap}

val (account_df_index, disposition_df_index) = if(extra_params.equals(None)) 
                        {
                        (0,1)
                        } else {
                        if(extra_params_map.contains("dataframe_index_map"){
                        val dataframe_map = 

                        extra_params_map.get("dataframe_index_map")
                        .get.parseJson
                        .convertTo[Map[String, Int]]
                        val account_df_index = dataframe_map.getOrElse("account", 0)
                        val disposition_df_index = dataframe_map.getOrElse("disposition", 1)
                        (account_df_index, disposition_df_index)
                        } else{
                              (0,1)
                              }
                        }
```

Comment: I have tried using None, Unit with .equals checks both throw the same issue: error: value contains is not a member of Equals
              if (extra_params_map.contains("dataframe_index_map"))

Comment: I've just attempted to indent it, but it seems just so completely broken beyond repair. Please make sure that your read the documentation about [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) (in particular `None`) and [Map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html), that you declare the type of each variable explicitly until you have at least a rough plan of what you are doing, and that the arities of the tuples on left hand side match the arities of tuples: 4>2. And also read [Style guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/indentation.html).

Comment: Bunch of unsorted hints: - don't compare with `equals`, `==` is usually sufficient; - don't compare anything to `None`, use pattern matching or `map` or `fold` on Options;

Comment: Sorry about the mismatch, I've edited it. I will look at map, fold and option. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with this code. I'll focus on two things.

**variable initialization via pattern matching**

```
val (a, b, c, d) = if (someCondition) doThis()
                   else               doThat()
```

In this example 4 different variables, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, are created and initialized. The compiler recognizes that they grouped in a 4-tuple and makes the pattern match *if the right side of the equals `=` returns a 4-tuple*. So this only works if *both* `doThis()` and `doThat()` *return the same thing*, i.e. a 4-tuple with the same type pattern.

**None is part of Option**

If a variable might be `None` then that variable's type is `Option[X]` where `X` is the type of the variable if it is *not* `None`.

```
val extra_params_map: Option[Map[Int,Int]] = if (extra_params.isEmpty) None 
                                             else Some(extra_params.toMap)
```

Notice that `Some()` is the compliment of `None` and the result type is `Option`. In this case it is `Option[Map[Int,Int]]` assuming that `extra_params.toMap` returns a `Map[Int,Int]`.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! So I'm guessing and you may know if this implies that the interpreter compiles the line of code before execution?

Comment: Scala is a compiled language. It is compiled before executed, even in the REPL.